# ARM64 architecture under fastdds long-time running failure

Tags: ros-humble, fastdds

**Required Info:**

- Operating System:

  - Ubuntu20.04, Arm64, Jetson Orin NX
- Installation type:

  - Docker `ros:humble-ros-base` image
- Version or commit hash:

  - Humble
- DDS implementation:

  - Fast-RTPS
- Client library (if applicable):

  - rclpy

##### Steps to reproduce issue

1. [Writing a simple publisher and subscriber in Python](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Py-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html)
2. Increase the sending frequency and message data volume.
3. ros2 run

##### Expected behavior

Program is running normally.

##### Actual behavior

Four hours later, the listener node no longer prints logs, and messages cannot be received through `ros2 topic echo topic` either.
[image]

After restarting the talker, everything returns to normal.
If I use **CycloneDDS**, there are no problems either.

##### Additional information

When running normally, data packets can be captured with tcpdump.
cmdline: `tcpdump -i any -X udp portrange 7401-7500`

```
10:14:15.294838 lo    In  IP localhost.52382 > localhost.7413: UDP, length 1188
        0x0000:  4500 04c0 abeb 4000 4011 8c3f 7f00 0001  E.....@.@..?....
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 cc9e 1cf5 04ac 02c0 5254 5053  ............RTPS
        0x0020:  0203 010f 010f 6b24 f908 8385 0100 0000  ......k$........
        0x0030:  0e01 0c00 010f 7ec0 8503 b3d0 0100 0000  ......~.........
        0x0040:  0901 0800 f780 0366 ce36 744b 1505 7004  .......f.6tK..p.
        0x0050:  0000 1000 0000 1104 0000 1103 0000 0000  ................
        0x0060:  5701 0000 0001 0000 5204 0000 4865 6c6c  W.......R...Hell
        0x0070:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x0080:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x0090:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x00a0:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x00b0:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x00c0:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x00d0:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x00e0:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x00f0:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x0100:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x0110:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x0120:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x0130:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x0140:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x0150:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x0160:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x0170:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x0180:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x0190:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x01a0:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x01b0:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x01c0:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x01d0:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x01e0:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x01f0:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x0200:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x0210:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x0220:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x0230:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x0240:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x0250:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x0260:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x0270:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x0280:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x0290:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x02a0:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x02b0:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x02c0:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x02d0:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x02e0:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x02f0:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x0300:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x0310:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x0320:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x0330:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x0340:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x0350:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x0360:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x0370:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x0380:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x0390:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x03a0:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x03b0:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x03c0:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x03d0:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x03e0:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x03f0:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x0400:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f  lo.WorldHello.Wo
        0x0410:  726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865  rldHello.WorldHe
        0x0420:  6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057  llo.WorldHello.W
        0x0430:  6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448  orldHello.WorldH
        0x0440:  656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20  ello.WorldHello.
        0x0450:  576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64  WorldHello.World
        0x0460:  4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f  Hello.WorldHello
        0x0470:  2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c  .WorldHello.Worl
        0x0480:  6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 4865 6c6c  dHello.WorldHell
        0x0490:  6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c 6c6f 2057 6f72  o.WorldHello.Wor
        0x04a0:  6c64 4865 6c6c 6f20 576f 726c 6448 656c  ldHello.WorldHel
        0x04b0:  6c6f 2057 6f72 6c64 3a20 3334 3200 0000  lo.World:.342...
```

After the talker crashes, tcpdump cannot capture any packets.

```
10:06:10.542177 lo    In  IP localhost.44357 > localhost.7412: UDP, length 420
        0x0000:  4500 01c0 c07e 4000 4011 7aac 7f00 0001  E....~@.@.z.....
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 ad45 1cf4 01ac ffbf 5254 5053  .....E......RTPS
        0x0020:  0203 010f 010f 7ec0 a103 dd31 0100 0000  ......~....1....
        0x0030:  0901 0800 f79e 0266 7f6a fe81 1505 8001  .......f.j......
        0x0040:  0000 1000 0001 00c7 0001 00c2 0000 0000  ................
        0x0050:  0100 0000 0003 0000 1500 0400 0203 0000  ................
        0x0060:  1600 0400 010f 0000 5000 1000 010f 7ec0  ........P.....~.
        0x0070:  a103 dd31 0100 0000 0000 01c1 3200 1800  ...1........2...
        0x0080:  0100 0000 f61c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0090:  0000 0000 c0a8 0370 3200 1800 0100 0000  .......p2.......
        0x00a0:  f61c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x00b0:  0a4c 51ba 3200 1800 0100 0000 f61c 0000  .LQ.2...........
        0x00c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ac12 0001  ................
        0x00d0:  3200 1800 0100 0000 f61c 0000 0000 0000  2...............
        0x00e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0a01 79da 3100 1800  ..........y.1...
        0x00f0:  1000 0000 f71c 0000 557e c000 0000 0000  ........U~......
        0x0100:  0000 0000 0000 0000 3100 1800 0100 0000  ........1.......
        0x0110:  f71c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0120:  c0a8 0370 3100 1800 0100 0000 f71c 0000  ...p1...........
        0x0130:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0a4c 51ba  .............LQ.
        0x0140:  3100 1800 0100 0000 f71c 0000 0000 0000  1...............
        0x0150:  0000 0000 0000 0000 ac12 0001 0200 0800  ................
        0x0160:  1400 0000 0000 0000 5800 0400 3f0c 0f00  ........X...?...
        0x0170:  6200 0800 0200 0000 2f00 0000 2c00 1000  b......./...,...
        0x0180:  0b00 0000 656e 636c 6176 653d 2f3b 0000  ....enclave=/;..
        0x0190:  5900 2800 0100 0000 1100 0000 5041 5254  Y.(.........PART
        0x01a0:  4943 4950 414e 545f 5459 5045 0000 0000  ICIPANT_TYPE....
        0x01b0:  0700 0000 5349 4d50 4c45 0000 0100 0000  ....SIMPLE......
10:06:10.890641 lo    In  IP localhost.49475 > localhost.7414: UDP, length 420
        0x0000:  4500 01c0 c0c2 4000 4011 7a68 7f00 0001  E.....@.@.zh....
        0x0010:  7f00 0001 c143 1cf6 01ac ffbf 5254 5053  .....C......RTPS
        0x0020:  0203 010f 010f 7ec0 8503 b3d0 0100 0000  ......~.........
        0x0030:  0901 0800 f19e 0266 7fce 47c5 1505 8001  .......f..G.....
        0x0040:  0000 1000 0001 00c7 0001 00c2 0000 0000  ................
        0x0050:  0100 0000 0003 0000 1500 0400 0203 0000  ................
        0x0060:  1600 0400 010f 0000 5000 1000 010f 7ec0  ........P.....~.
        0x0070:  8503 b3d0 0100 0000 0000 01c1 3200 1800  ............2...
        0x0080:  0100 0000 f41c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0090:  0000 0000 c0a8 0370 3200 1800 0100 0000  .......p2.......
        0x00a0:  f41c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x00b0:  0a4c 51ba 3200 1800 0100 0000 f41c 0000  .LQ.2...........
        0x00c0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ac12 0001  ................
        0x00d0:  3200 1800 0100 0000 f41c 0000 0000 0000  2...............
        0x00e0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0a01 79da 3100 1800  ..........y.1...
        0x00f0:  1000 0000 f51c 0000 557e c000 0000 0000  ........U~......
        0x0100:  0000 0000 0000 0000 3100 1800 0100 0000  ........1.......
        0x0110:  f51c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
        0x0120:  c0a8 0370 3100 1800 0100 0000 f51c 0000  ...p1...........
        0x0130:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0a4c 51ba  .............LQ.
        0x0140:  3100 1800 0100 0000 f51c 0000 0000 0000  1...............
        0x0150:  0000 0000 0000 0000 ac12 0001 0200 0800  ................
        0x0160:  1400 0000 0000 0000 5800 0400 3f0c 0f00  ........X...?...
        0x0170:  6200 0800 0200 0000 2f00 0000 2c00 1000  b......./...,...
        0x0180:  0b00 0000 656e 636c 6176 653d 2f3b 0000  ....enclave=/;..
        0x0190:  5900 2800 0100 0000 1100 0000 5041 5254  Y.(.........PART
        0x01a0:  4943 4950 414e 545f 5459 5045 0000 0000  ICIPANT_TYPE....
        0x01b0:  0700 0000 5349 4d50 4c45 0000 0100 0000  ....SIMPLE......
```

---

talker.py:

```py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.1  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World' * 100 + ': %d' % self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.i += 1
        if self.i % 50 == 0:
            self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%d"' % self.i)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Listener.py:

````py
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_subscriber')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            'topic',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning
        self.i = 0

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        self.i += 1
        if self.i % 50 == 0:
            self.get_logger().info('I heard: "%s"' % msg.data.split(':')[-1])


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = MinimalSubscriber()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```
````